# two exact same code but one of the code has zombie issue

Tags: ios, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks, nszombie

in rootviewcontroller this code is working fine

```
- (IBAction)gotoAboutGame:(id)sender
{
    aboutGame *aboutGameObj = [[aboutGame alloc]init];

    [UIView transitionFromView:self.view toView:aboutGameObj.view duration:2 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [aboutGameObj release];
    }];

    [self release];
}
```

but from aboutgame when i am coming back to rootviewcontroller i am getting zombie attacks

```
- (IBAction)gotoMain:(id)sender
{
ViewController *viewControllerObj = [[ViewController alloc]init];

    [UIView transitionFromView:self.view toView:viewControllerObj.view duration:2 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [viewControllerObj release];
    }];

    [self release];
}
```

it shows the rootviewcontroller view but as i touch any button zombie attacks.

Comment: +1 for "zombie attacks".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What class is this code in?

This line looks very suspect to me

```
[self release];
```

Why it the object releasing itself? Surely the object that created it should be doing this.

Comment: self is the object of current class after the switching to another view i am releasing the current class so this way viewcontroller of current class will be released to prevent memory leak

Comment: I understand what self is, but I have rarely seen this done. There must be an object that owns these two controllers? For example normally I would expect the object that created the viewController to be responsible for releasing it.

Comment: gotoAboutGame method is declared in rootviewcontroller and gotoMain method is declared in aboutgame.m and i am creating objects beginning of the methods ..... i have a very small quiz project can i send it to u so u can check what foolishness i am doing i am new that y having so much problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
[viewControllerObj release];
```

put  it  after  animation  block

Comment: i also did that but app crashes .... if i place this after animation block this code will show the next view but viewcontroller will released so as i touch any button app chashes ... plz tell me 1 more thing this code make next view a rootviewcontroller?? and what is the best way to swap views in ios? thats what i m pursuing for about a month but didnt find the best way to swap between ios views without nav or tabbarcontroller

Answer (score 0):

- by convention, class names begin with capital letters, not lowercase
- your memory management is quite wrong;  `[self release]` is pretty much never correct (there are very esoteric cases where it is).   What `retain` is that supposed to balance?

Comment: then how to manage memory when swaping views .. apps starts first thing is rootviewcontroller i switched to aboutgame then aboutgame became rootviewcontroller so i cleaned the previous viewcontroller by releasing it

Comment: See the examples related to UIViewControllers linked to at the top of the UIViewController class documentation.  Better yet, turn on ARC (automatic reference counting) and don't worry about it.